# Jquery button behavior for select all in datatable.

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

I am writing a selectall button for the jquery datatable in my application. But the button is behaving in inconsistent manner and double clicking the button actually unselects the checkboxes in datatable. Here is my code for the button click event. sampleTable is my jquery datatable.

```
$("#button_select_all").click(function () {
       $(allSamplesTable.fnGetFilteredNodes()).find(':checkbox').each(function () {
       $this = $(this);
       $this.attr('checked', 'checked');

                    for (var i = 0; i < _sampleTableExports.length; i++) {
                        if (_sampleTableExports[i]["Id"] == $(this).val()) {
                            _sampleTableExports.splice(i, 1);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    _sampleTableExports.push({ "Name": $(this).attr("name"), "Id": $(this).val() });
                });

            });
```

Kindly advise why the button is unslecting the checkboxes in the 2nd click.

Comment: is the `button_select_all` element a button or a checkbox?

Comment: I have it as an external button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$this.attr('checked', 'checked');
```

could you try

```
$this.prop('checked', true);
```

If you only want the select all to fire once try this:

```
$("#button_select_all").one( "click", function() {
    // Place your click logic in here
        // $(allSamplesTable.fnGetFilteredNodes()).find......
});
```

But otherwise it seems like your check all button is behaving as it should, click once it selects everything, click again it de-selects everything.

Comment: @GBP Thanks. I tried using that. It still unchecks the chekcboxes on 2nd click. Its flipping switch on every click.